# Copy a file from one folder to another in php only if file has changed

Tags: php

How can I copy a file (example: `adresses.txt`) in PHP from one folder (original folder) to another folder (backup folder) only if file (filesize?) has changed?

The code should be check if the 2 files are the same (compare the files in original folder and backup folder), if not then copy the file from original folder to backup folder, if files are the same then do nothing.

I hope, someone can help me.

Thank you,
Oliver

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far (some code).

Comment: Why would you do this via filesize comparison? File modification time would seem more logical since a file which changes from `this is a sentence` into `this sentence is a` is the same exact size.

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for copying the file, but I´m a PHP-Beginner, and don´t know how I can check the files with IF/ELSE:

```
$newfile = '../wp-content/plugins/inmotion-medien/info/adresses.txt';
$oldfile = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/adresses.txt";

copy($newfile, $oldfile)
```

But I don´t know how I can check if `$newfile` is the same as `$oldfile` and if `$newfile` is newer then overwrite `$oldfile` If it is better to check the modification time it is ok, but I don´t know how I do that.

Comment: `if (filesize( $newfile ) !== filesize( $oldfile )) {
copy($newfile, $oldfile) 
}`